# Nodejs, Expressjs with EJS to Android doens't work in PhoneGap?

Tags: node.js, cordova, express, phonegap-build, ejs

I have a nodejs + expressjs app that needs to be converted to an android. A quick solution that we are thinking of is to use phonegap. The issue I am stuck with is all my files under view folder of the web app are ejs files.

When I try to upload my app to phonegap it says no index.html found in my .zip folder.

My question here is:
1. Should I separate the front end files from the node app? using html and pure js?
2. Is there a way I can render ejs files on to html files (something like import) so that I can convert existing web app into an android app?
3. Is there an option in phonegap to use ejs files instead of html files?

I am using https://build.phonegap.com/ for converting the app. Someone please help as I am stuck with this for a long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NodeJS/Express is for backend side, so, you can't package it to an Phonegap app.

In your Phonegap application you can only have HTML and JS (and others ressources like images...).

> 1. Should I separate the front end files from the node app?

Yes and then you have to create some webservices to get your data from backend to frontend.

> 2. Is there a way I can render ejs files on to html files

As far as I can read over internet, it's not recommanded to use EJS on frontend side...

> 3. Is there an option in phonegap to use ejs files instead of html files?

No, no way.

A phonegap app have a defined achitecture, please see/clone: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-start which give you a good exemple.

Hope this answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Think this way:

You will run your app **locally** only, no server, no localhost, nothing. How can you render a template language as EJS locally?
There is no way to use EJS with Phonegap app, you should use only .html and .js files.